# Background color of spinner item gets randomly change

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner which has a list of items that are populating from a db query. I'm changing the background color of the spinner items based on the data found in my local sqlite db. Everything is working fine except when I scroll the list in my spinner, other items which shouldn't get change its background color, changes its background color too.

I'm well aware of the recycling issue in android listview and I've implemented the holder pattern to solve it but I'm facing difficulties in solving the issue in my spinner list.

This is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Category> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, categoryList){
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

            Category category = (Category) getItem(position);
            Cursor crsCheckCatAva = database.rawQuery("SELECT distinct category_id FROM "+ ItemsTable.TABLE_OUTLET_DATA +" WHERE "+ ItemsTable.COLUMN_OUTLET_DATA_OUTLET_ID +"='"+ Info.getInstance().getOutletID() +"'", null);
            if(crsCheckCatAva.getCount() > 0){
                while (crsCheckCatAva.moveToNext()){
                    if(category.getCategory_id() == 0){
                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }else
                    if(crsCheckCatAva.getInt(crsCheckCatAva.getColumnIndex("category_id")) == category.getCategory_id()){
                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    }
                }
            }
            crsCheckCatAva.close();
        return row;
    }
};
categorySelectionSpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
```

Comment: design your own custom adapter. Perform the db process in activity thread by adding the cusor to the list and pass the final list to the adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution and this is what I did:

I was returning the convertView everytime no matter what the conditions were. What I did was I returned the convertView only if the db id matched the id otherwise I returned convertview as null. This is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Category> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, categoryList){
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);

                    Category category = (Category) getItem(position);
                    Cursor crsCheckCatAva = database.rawQuery("SELECT distinct category_id FROM "+ ItemsTable.TABLE_OUTLET_DATA +" WHERE "+ ItemsTable.COLUMN_OUTLET_DATA_OUTLET_ID +"='"+ Info.getInstance().getOutletID() +"'", null);
                    if(crsCheckCatAva.getCount() > 0){
                        while (crsCheckCatAva.moveToNext()){
                            /*if(category.getCategory_id() == 0){
                                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            }else*/
                            if(crsCheckCatAva.getInt(crsCheckCatAva.getColumnIndex("category_id")) == category.getCategory_id()){
                                row = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            }
                        }
                    }else {
                        row = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
                    }
                    crsCheckCatAva.close();
                return row;
            }
        };
        categorySelectionSpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
```